# Find $m$ such that $(m-1)x^{2}+(m-1)x+m-3<0$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I need to find $m$ real parameter such that $(m-1)x^{2}+(m-1)x+m-3<0$ for all real $x$.

My try: First condition $m-1<0$ so $m<1$

Second condition: the discriminant $<0$ from which I got $m\in(-\infty,1)\cup(\frac{11}{3},\infty)$
So when I intersectate the intervals I get $m\in(-\infty,1)$ which in my book is the wrong answer.
I need to chose from: A. m does not exist. B. $m\in(-\infty,1)\cup(\frac{11}{3},\infty)$ C. $m\in(-\infty,0)$ D.$m\in(-\infty,1)$ E.Another answer (The right answer is E.)
I miss something?

Comment: Maybe you missed $m = 1$? For $m = 2$ your function is $\equiv -2$ therefore it is < 0 for all $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer was almost correct; the assumption $m-1<0$ is not quite correct and should have been $\le$. Note $m=1$ works since you simply obtain $-2$ for all $x$, giving $(-\infty, 1]$.

Answer (score 3):

If you write

$$(m-1)x^{2}+(m-1)x+m-3<0 \Leftrightarrow (m-1)\underbrace{(x^2 + x +1)}_{> 0 \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}} <2 $$

and note that $\lim_{x\to \infty}(x^2+x+1) = +\infty$ you get immediately without further calculations

$$m-1 \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow \boxed{m \leq 1}$$